# How do I set JAVA_HOME for libGDX?

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm creating my second game using libGDX. After downloading the Setup App, I've set my options as shown in the pictures.

[image]

[image]

Where is the JAVA_HOME variable and how do I set it? What is PATH?

Answer (score 0):

Well, PATH is the system variable that your operating system uses to locate needed executables from the command line or terminal. Open window terminal and type:

```
echo %JAVA_HOME%
```

It should return something like this:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk_version
```

Use [this](https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/setting-the-java_home-variable-in-windows-8895.html) manual, for example, to install variable manually.

Usually, the JAVA_HOME is set during installation, but it may fail for various reasons, for example, the system has several different versions of Java.